# How can I use LLVM call a function with variable parameters in my std library

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, llvm-ir

Now I am trying to develop a compiler.I want a "print" function.It can be used like this:

```
print(90, "hello world")
```

Before,I use a list(or vector) to hold the arguments.But now I want to use LLVM.And I don't know how to make llvm ir to call this.In my mind,maybe I should build a dynamic or static library to store my std library,but if I use `declare print(...)` in llvm ir.I will miss the type infomation.Is there any way to record the type infomation?Or there is any better way.

I will appreciate it if anyone can help me!

Answer (score 1):

Functions with variable number of parameters in LLVM are handled in the same [way](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic), as they are handled in C.

To handle it, LLVM IR has special opcodes: `VASTART`, `VAARG`, `VACOPY` and `VAEND`, see [ISD](https://llvm.org/doxygen/namespacellvm_1_1ISD.html) docs for details.